# Accessing H2 Console While Running SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

If I'm running a test with `@SpringBootTest` is there any way to access the H2 console?  I have a test that accesses an H2 database (successfully), but if I want to inspect the database myself, how can I?

I started by running the test with a `webEnvironment=DEFINED_PORT` and http://localhost:8080/ responds to HTTP, but there's nothing http://localhost:8080/h2-console/ still responds with 404.

I tried turning on the console explicitly by adding values to `application.properties`:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

That seemed to have no effect. Still 404s at `/h2-console` and `/h2`.

The H2 Console seems to come in through Auto-Configuration, so I turned on the auto configuration report using `-Ddebug`, and I can see that despite the enabled flag being on in application.properties, it's seen as being off:

```
H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration: 
      Did not match:
          - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.h2.console.enabled=true) did not find property 'enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.h2.server.web.WebServlet'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
         - found WebApplicationContext (OnWebApplicationCondition)
```

Seems like some mechanism is overriding the value or ignoring the value from `application.properties` while running the test.

Does Spring Boot Test not start up the console? Is there any way to convince it to do so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I was able to get it to appear with the following annotation (in Kotlin):
`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = arrayOf("spring.h2.console.enabled=true"))`

Even with this, the console is still at `/h2-console`, so it's clearly ignoring the console path as well. I could presumably control that by adding another property.